# An abelian $p$-group has a bounded basic subgroup iff it is the direct sum of a divisible group and bounded group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-sum, p-groups

This is **Exercise 4.3.8** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)*". According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AAbelian%2C%20OR%20content%3Agroup%2C%20OR%20content%3Abounded%2C%20OR%20content%3Abasic%2C%20OR%20content%3Adivisible&p=10), it is new to MSE.

(*NB:* Modules aren't covered in Robinson's book yet.)

### The Details:

> Let $p$ be prime. A [*$p$-group*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) is a group all of whose elements have a $p$ power order.

On page 12 of Robinson's book,

> A *torsion group* [. . .] is a group all of whose elements have finite order.

On page 94, *ibid.*,

> An element $g$ of an abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* in $G$ by a positive integer $m$ if $g=mg_1$ for some $g_1$ in $G$. [. . .]
>
> An abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* of each element is divisible by every positive integer.

On page 106, *ibid.*,

> A subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$ is called *pure* if
>
> $$nG\cap H=nH$$
>
> for all integers $n\ge 0$.

On page 107, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be an abelian torsion group. A subgroup $B$ is called a *basic subgroup* if it is pure in $G$, it is the direct sum of cyclic groups, and $G/B$ is divisible.

On page 108, *ibid.*,

> An additively written group is called *bounded* if its elements have boundedly finite orders: [. . .] multiplicative groups with this property are said to have finite exponent.

### The Question:

> An abelian $p$-group has a bounded basic subgroup if and only if it is the direct sum of a divisible group and a bounded group.

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ be an abelian $p$-group.

---

There's a lot going on here. Divisible groups familiar to me:

- [An abelian, characteristically simple group is divisible (supposedly).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3943618/104041)
- [The pure subgroups of a divisible abelian group are just the direct summands.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222503/104041)
- [Show that a group, given by a presentation, is countable & reduced with a nontrivial element of infinite height](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240323/104041)

Of course, so are abelian groups, $p$-groups, cyclic groups, bounded groups (in their multiplicative form), [pure subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222503/104041), torsion groups, and direct sums.

---

[I think $G$ has to be infinite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/956595/104041)

---

It might be easier to consider when $G$ is finitely generated, since then we could use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups to get $G$ as a direct sum of some groups; I'm not sure how to take it from there. However, **Theorem 4.2.9**, page 103, *ibid.*, states,

> A finitely generated abelian group $G$ is finite if it is a torsion group.

---

This is a question I think I could answer myself. However, I'm coming towards the end of my degree so I don't have enough time to spend on reading textbooks thoroughly - but I think I would lose momentum in Robinson's book if I left it any longer. The kind of answer I'm hoping for is a full solution.

---

Please help :)

Comment: One direction should be clear: since divisible groups are not bounded, if $G=D\oplus B$ with $B$ bounded and $D$ divisible, then $B$ is basic (and bounded). Conversely, if $G$ has a basic bounded subgroup $B$, and $D$ is any divisible subgroup of $G$, then $B\cap D$ must be trivial. I would take a maximal divisible subgroup of $G$ and try to show that $G$ is the sum of $B$ and such a subgroup.

Comment: Scratch the second part... No divisible subgroup does not mean intersection with any divisible subgroup is trivial. As any proper nontrivial subgroup of the Prufer group shows.

Comment: Okay, if $B$ is basic, $D$ divisible, and $x\in D\cap B$, write $B$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups; then $x$ lies in a finite sum $C_{p^{a_1}}\oplus\cdots \oplus C_{p^{a_k}}$ which is a direct summand of $B$. Since $B$ is pure and $x\in nG$ for all $n\gt 0$, then $x\in nB$ for all $n\gt 0$, and in particular $x\in p^{a_1+\cdots+a_k}B$, But this implies that $x$ is in fact trivial, so $B\cap D$ is indeed trivial.