# An abelian torsion group has a unique basic subgroup iff it is divisible or bounded.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups, torsion-groups, divisible-groups

This is **Exercise 4.3.14** of Robinson's  *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AAbelian%20torsion%20group%2C%20OR%20content%3Aunique%2C%20OR%20content%3Abasic%20subgroup&p=8), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

> Let $p$ be prime. A [*$p$-group*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) is a group all of whose elements have a $p$ power order.

On page 12 of Robinson's book,

> A *torsion group* [. . .] is a group all of whose elements have finite order.

On page 94, *ibid.*,

> An element $g$ of an abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* in $G$ by a positive integer $m$ if $g=mg_1$ for some $g_1$ in $G$. [. . .]
>
> An abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* of each element is divisible by every positive integer.

On page 106, *ibid.*,

> A subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$ is called *pure* if
>
> $$nG\cap H=nH$$
>
> for all integers $n\ge 0$.

On page 107, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be an abelian torsion group. A subgroup $B$ is called a *basic subgroup* if it is pure in $G$, it is the direct sum of cyclic groups, and $G/B$ is divisible.

On page 108, *ibid.*,

> An additively written group is called *bounded* if its elements have boundedly finite orders.

### The Question:

> (Kulikov) Prove that an abelian torsion group has a unique basic subgroup if and only if it is divisible or bounded. [*Hint:* Let $B$ be the unique basic subgroup of the $p$-group $G$. Write $B=\langle x\rangle \oplus B_1$ and show that $G=\langle x\rangle \oplus G_1$ for some $G_1$. If $a\in G_1$ and $\lvert a\rvert\le\lvert x\rvert$, prove that the assignments $x\mapsto xa$ and $g_1\mapsto g_1$, $(g_1\in G_1)$, determine an automorphism of $G$. Deduce that $a\in B$.]

### Thoughts:

The hint, in essence, I think, suggests that I use **Exercise 4.3.8**. I asked about that exercise here earlier:

- [An abelian $p$-group has a bounded basic subgroup iff it is the direct sum of a divisible group and bounded group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246158/104041)

---

Let $G$ be an abelian torsion group.

---

$\Rightarrow$

Suppose $B$ is a unique basic subgroup of $G$.

What allows us to assume $G$ is a $p$-group, following the hint?

---

$\Leftarrow$

It seems natural to use the following logical equivalence:

$$((D\lor B)\to U)\leftrightarrow ((D\to U)\land (B\to U)).$$

- $(D\implies U)$

Suppose $G$ is divisible. Then for all $g\in G$ we have for all $m\in\Bbb N$ there exists an $h\in G$ with

$$g=mh.$$

What do I do next? I have nothing nontrivial to add.

- $(B\implies U)$

Let $G$ be bounded. Then each $g\in G$ has boundedly finite order.

This is a stronger assertion than saying $G$ is a torsion group.

Again, I have nothing nontrivial to add.

---

I have skipped a few exercises from **Section 4.3** of the book. This is primarily because I have spent too much time on the set; I forgot too much of what came before and I began to lose patience in myself. I chose this exercise because it seems interesting and I have experience with a similar problem (see above).

If I had more time, I think I could solve this myself. There's a lot going on in my life at the moment, though, so I cannot devote too much to one exercise, especially considering that the exercise is not marked as being referred to later on in the text.

---

Please help :)

Comment: For bounded groups $G$, if $B\leq G$ and $G/B$ is divisible (and bounded), then $G/B=1$. Thus $B=G$ and hence is unique.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidA.Craven :)

Comment: Every quotient of a divisible group is divisible (if $x=n\cdot y$ then $x+H=n\cdot (y+H)$), so if $G$ is torsion divisible, we need that it has no non-trivial basic subgroups $B$. But torsion divisible groups are direct sums of quasicyclic groups (4.1.5), and pure subgroups are just direct summands by Exercise 4.3.3. Quasicyclic subgroups are not sums of cyclic subgroups, so $B=1$.

Comment: Finally, I know Sylow's theorem is still not allowed, but for torsion abelian groups the set of all elements of order a power of $p$ is a subgroup, and a torsion group is the direct sum of these over all $p$. I'm sure Robinson uses this all the time. If $G=\bigoplus_p G_p$ has a unique basic subgroup $B$, then $B=\bigoplus_p B_p$, and so the question is whether $B_p$ is basic in $G_p$. Clearly it is a sum of cyclic groups, $G_p/B_p$ is divisible, and so pure is all that is needed. This is also clear from the fact that $B$ is pure in $G$.

Comment: Please consider upgrading those comments to an answer, @DavidA.Craven.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a CW answer adapting the comments by @DavidA.Craven above.*

For bounded groups $G$, if $B\le G$ and $G/B$ is divisible (and bounded), then $G/B=1$. Thus $B=G$ and hence is unique.

Every quotient of a divisible group is divisible (if $x=n\cdot y$ then $x+H=n\cdot(y+H)$), so if $G$ is torsion divisible, we need that it has no non-trivial basic subgroups $B$. But torsion divisible groups are direct sums of quasicyclic groups (4.1.5), and pure subgroups are just direct summands by Exercise 4.3.3. Quasicyclic subgroups are not sums of cyclic subgroups, so $B=1.$

Finally, I know Sylow's theorem is still not allowed, but for torsion abelian groups the set of all elements of order a power of $p$ is a subgroup, and a torsion group is the direct sum of these over all $p$. I'm sure Robinson uses this all the time. If $G=\oplus_pG_p$ has a unique basic subgroup $B$, then $B=\oplus_pB_p$, and so the question is whether $B_p$ is basic in $G_p$. Clearly it is a sum of cyclic groups, $G_p/B_p$ is divisible, and so pure is all that is needed. This is also clear from the fact that $B$ is pure in $G$.